# we are burdened by repressions resulting from our early family life

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does

> Post-Freudians have reminded us how we are burdened by repressions resulting from our early family life, Marxists and Foucauldians by the power of the political hegemonies we labour under or subscribe to.

Mean:

1. Post-Freudians have reminded us how we are burdened by repressions resulting from our early family life, Marxists, and Foucauldians and by the power of the political hegemonies we labour under or subscribe to.

or

2. Post-Freudians have reminded us how we are burdened by repressions resulting from our early family life and how Marxists and Foucauldians are burdened by the power of the political hegemonies we labour under or subscribe to.

Answer (score 2):

This would be clearer if the comma after "family life" were a semicolon.

You may conclude from the context of the named movements that the sentence contrasts theories of personal burdens.  Freudians ascribe their weight to early family life.  Marxists, on the other hand, ascribe that weight to the political power structures of society.

Answer (score 0):

To use your own words from version two:

> Post-Freudians have reminded us how we are burdened by repressions
>   resulting from our early family life...

and

> Marxists and Foucauldians  **have reminded us how we are burdened
>   by** the power of the political hegemonies we labour under or
>   subscribe to.